# Pixels are not being drawn to screen and unable to quit. May be MacOSX related bug?

Tags: c, xcode5, sdl, sdl-2

I'm following [this](http://www.programmersranch.com/2014/02/sdl2-pixel-drawing.html) tutorial on SDL. I tried translating the code to C, which can be viewed [here](https://github.com/karadon/gameOfLife/blob/master/gameOfLife/main.c). As you can guess, I want to use this code in an implementation of Conway's Game of Life. The code compiles and runs, and a white screen is drawn. But I am not getting any pixels drawn to the screen when I click around, and the program does not quit when I press the red OSX quit button or select quit from the menu.

If you look at the comments section of the tutorial, you can see that I asked the author of the tutorial the same question. He replied saying that the code works for him and that my problem may be due to a bug with OSX. I tried asking the forum that he recommended, but posting to the forum requires special user privileges that I haven't yet been granted. Sticking SDL_GetError() in various places in my program doesn't change the behavior of the program either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more widely known (but incomplete) tutorial is located [here](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/index.html). I don't know if that helps.

Use SDL_PollEvent() instead of SDL_WaitEvent(). The reason for this is that WaitEvent waits untill an event happens (pausing the program) while PollEvent does not. Second the events should be handled in a loop ie: `while(SDL_PollEvent(&e) {...}` not `SDL_WaitEvent(&e);...`

The best thing for you do do is follow the other tutorials that I linked to since the tutorial you are using does not seem to be very well written. (you can just quickly reed through the stuff you already know)